# Parsing email from query string

Tags: javascript, query-string, analytics

I'm trying to create a piece of JS that will parse the email address from a url query string. Once that's done, I want it to send the results to anaytics for use in whatever I need to use it in.

so basically abc.com?wemail=abc@abc.com

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*Extracts email from query string using ?email=name@abc.com*/

function GetUrlValue(VarSearch) {
  var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++) {
    var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
    if (KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch) {
      return KeyValuePair[1];
    }
  }
```

The anayltics is receiving the data, but the @ sign is being replaced by %40 and it isn't coding it the way I want.

I'm sure that is it simple, but what changes need to be made to ensure this works properly?

Answer (score 1):

The %40 symbol you are getting is the encoded url symbol for the @ symbol. 
Refer to the link which refers to the usage of

> decodeURIComponent() function in javascript

[url decode function javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

please check this link out

Answer (score 0):

The `@` symbol is a originally used when the URL contains authentication info:

```
user:pass@myurl.com
```

So modern browsers will encode the `@` symbol in query string to `%40`. Use `decodeURIComponent()` to decode the value before sending to Segment.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent